# I have an error "E sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Can't find any foreign key relationships between 'user_test' and 'payments_test'

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, pytest, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using flask-sqlalchemy. I am getting an error "E sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Can't find any foreign key relationships between 'user_test' and 'payments_test'." My error I assume is caused by not having the right name for the FK column or the relationship.

If I were to change the table in the `UserTest` table to `__tablename__= user_test` and the `__PaymentsTest__= payments_tests` table how would that change the relationship column and the FK column?

Also I didn't include all the columns in the tables and I don't want to use a join because the tables were working outside of pytest.

The only difference is that the Pytest tables have `Test` added to the class and since this the second database specifically for pytest I included the bind_key.

```
class UserTest(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    paymentstest = db.relationship('PaymentsTest', backref='UserTest', lazy=True) 
    bind_key = "testing_app_db"

def __repr__(self):
    return '<UserTest %r>' % self.username

class PaymentsTest(db.Model):
    '''
    One to many relationship
    This is the Many relationship. 
    '''
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    item_name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    usertest_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user_test.id'))
    bind_key = "testing_app_db"

    
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<PaymentsTest %r>' % self.item_name
```

`

Here is the full error.

https://hastebin.com/share/qucocologo.swift

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing is caused by SQLAlchemy not being able to find a foreign key between the 'user_test' and 'payments_test' tables. This is likely due to the way you are declaring the foreign key in the PaymentsTest model.

In SQLAlchemy, when you set up a foreign key, the table name is usually written in lower case. So, instead of referencing 'user_test.id' in your foreign key, you should reference 'usertest.id'.

Also, it's important to ensure that you've correctly imported and configured the Flask-SQLAlchemy extension. Here's how you can fix the error:

```
class UserTest(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'usertest'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    paymentstest = db.relationship('PaymentsTest', backref='user', lazy=True)
    bind_key = "testing_app_db"

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<UserTest %r>' % self.username


class PaymentsTest(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'paymentstest'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    item_name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    usertest_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('usertest.id'))
    bind_key = "testing_app_db"

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<PaymentsTest %r>' % self.item_name
```

Here, I've added __ tablename __ to each class to explicitly define the table name instead of letting SQLAlchemy infer the table name based on the class name. Now the foreign key in PaymentsTest refers to 'usertest.id' which is the correct table and column name.

Please try this fix and see if the error persists.

Comment: I tried what you are saying and I am still getting an error, https://hastebin.com/share/icolurudew.swift.